# ATG CSC session time out value need to change

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

We have a one requirement in ATG CSC side. We have by default session timeout for CSC user is 30 minute but the new requirement is coming up and they want to extend this timeout lets take an example they want it for 1 hour. We have tried in SessionManager seesionInvalidtime value, we tried to change session timeout value through web.xml but not any use. So my question is do you guys aware or know where can resolve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apart from ATG and web.xml, have you tried configuring server side? See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/configure_the_http_session_timeout

Comment: Yes, we have fixed the issue instead of web.xml, we need to change in jboss-web.xml but only thing is remaining that it should be permanent  value there because right now whenever we build it got override the value. Thanks for your comment